# Prove the part of the graph of $f$ on $I$ is never below the tangent line to the graph at $(c,f(c))$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f''(x) \geq 0, \forall x\in I$. If $c\in I$, show that the part of the graph of $f$ on $I$ is never below the tangent line to the graph at $(c,f(c))$.

I do not understand the question and I don't know how to begin. Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: You want to show $f(x) \ge l(x),$ where $l$ is the line tangent to the graph of $f$ at $(c,f(c).$

Comment: how do i find this tangent line? nothing else is given about $f$....

Comment: The canonical example is $y=f(x)=x^2$.  The second derivative is positive,, and if we draw a tangent line anywhere, the graph of $y=x^2$ is never below the tangent line. For the general argument, note that the tangent line at $x=c$ has equation $y=f'(c)(x-c)+f(c)$. We want to show that for all $x$ we have $f(x)\ge f'(c)(x-c)+f(c)$. The tool to use is the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: You can use integration on the inequality though a bit non-rigours to approach $y\geq ax+b $ so this is your minima function a straight line. Do you see where its going? @diya

Comment: @Mann I'm afraid the integration method is becoming a bit complicated for me.... thanks though :)

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you! I think i get it! $f''(x)\geq 0 \Rightarrow f'(x)$ is increasing. By MVT I get a $c<\alpha<x$ such that $\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(\alpha) \geq f'(c)$. Am I correct?

Comment: Very good, almost exactly. We need to also worry about $x\lt c$, but basically the same idea works. You could write it up as an answer.

Comment: You can also see the condition for concavity or convexity for a function. I just realized the result directly follows from that too @diya